# Bundle Node.js dependancies in AWS Zip

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, ffmpeg

Im creating a lambda function using Node.js, and Im looking to bundle the dependencies into my zip to be used in my Lambda function in AWS. Specifically Im using the **ffmpeg** library, and I've got it running locally using **npm**. Is there a way that I can bundle this dependency with the .zip file that I upload so that I don't have to configure the dependency in AWS?

Comment: I'm not sure what your Lambda code does, but don't forget about the transcoding capability offered by Amazon.  This is effectively FFmpeg, and can often be cheaper than doing it in your own instances fired up with Lambda.

Comment: Thanks @Brad, I'll look into that as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is there a way to bundle this into your deployment package, but you have to do it this way. Lambda functions can't download dependencies.

Here's the documenation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html

Also you might want to look at this project: https://github.com/binoculars/aws-lambda-ffmpeg and possibly this thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=680948 for more specific information about running ffmpeg on Lambda.

Comment: This is exactly what Im looking for. Thanks a lot!